# Library class not found when running RSpec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rubygems

I am working on a gem (not rails stuff just Ruby) and so far the code is working great but I am having the following error when running "rspec" from the gem root folder:

```
$ rspec
spec/logfile_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant LogFile (NameError)
...
```

This is how my gem is organised:

```
$ ls -R lib
logmsg    logmsg.rb

lib/logmsg:
logfile.rb version.rb yaml

lib/logmsg/yaml:
logmsg.yml
```

And my specs:

```
$ ls -R spec/
logfile_spec.rb logmsg_spec.rb  spec_helper.rb
```

Here are the contents of some files:

### - spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'logmsg'

RSpec.configure do |config|
    ...
end
```

### - spec/logmsg_spec.rb (this one works fine when I test it separately)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Logmsg do
  it 'has a version number' do
    expect(Logmsg::VERSION).not_to be nil
  end
end
```

### - spec/logfile_spec.rb (this is the one giving me some headaches)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe LogFile do
  subject { Logmsg::LogFile.new('test') }

  its(:name)            { should_not be nil }
  its(:datetime_format) { should_not be nil }
  its(:format)          { should_not be nil }
  its(:path)            { should_not be nil }

  context "registered" do
    its(:registered) { should be true }
  end

  context 'not registered' do
    its(:registered) { should be false }
  end
end
```

### - lib/logmsg.rb

```
require 'psych'
require 'logmsg/version'
require 'logmsg/logfile'

module Logmsg

  class LogMsg
    ...
  end
end
```

### - lib/logmsg/logfile.rb (this is the one that it had the class not being found)

```
require 'logger'

module Logmsg

  class LogFile
    ...
  end
end
```

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you write this:

```
describe LogFile do
```

Rspec goes looking for lib/log_file.rb, and raises that error when it doesn't find it. You can either change that description to a string:

```
describe `LogFile` do
```

or give it a location where it *can* be found:

```
describe Logmsg::LogFile do
```

Comment: Indeed, I was not aware of that. Thanks! It threw now a different error but related to something else entirely so I think the one I part of this question was resolved by your tip! Thanks again!